# How to send a value to route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to send a value to route that i am received from the controller.!How can i do it.

My controller:

```
public function payment_history($id)
    {   
        $payment_details=AmountDrvPaidHistoryModel::where('driver_id',$id)->get();

        return view('admin.driver_payment_history')->with('payment_details',$payment_details)->with(array('id'=>$id));
    }
```

Here is my blade:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('driver_payment_history/'.$id)}}" method="post">
```

How can i get the value of id in action tag that is send to another route.

Comment: try this {{ url(''driver_payment_history', [$id]) }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove array from this

```
->with('id'=>$id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code will be:

```
public function payment_history($id)
{   
    $payment_details = AmountDrvPaidHistoryModel::where('driver_id',$id)->get();

    return view('admin.driver_payment_history', compact('payment_details', 'id'));
}
```

With `compact` you can get the variable data, so `$id` will pass on to the view.

Than you can get the `id` with this code:

```
<form action="{{ url('driver_payment_history/'.$id) }}" method="post">
```

---

**EDIT**

```
<form action="{{ url('driver_payment_history/'.$payment_details[0]->driver_id) }}" method="post">
```

Hope this works!

Comment: It will show error like Undefined variable: $id (View: /home/whitehou/public_html/demo/HaloCab/resources/views/admin/driver_payment_history.blade.php)

Comment: but in url the value is appear

Comment: still same error..! i want value of id.you are send id as string 'id' then how it will give id value

Comment: That does the method `compact()`. But you can also try the code I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the `$id` inside your function, initiating it to be passed by the specific function.

```
public function payment_history($id) //<-this is the parameter passed into the function 
{   
    $payment_details=AmountDrvPaidHistoryModel::where('driver_id',$id)->get();
    $new_var_id = $id; //<- Assign the $id to a new variable (eg. $new_var_id)

    return view('admin.driver_payment_history',compact('payment_details','new_var_id');
}
```

You will then access the variable as such 
`<form action="{{ url('driver_payment_history/'.$new_var_id) }}" method="post">`

However keep in mind that you are **already** doing a get request with the `$id` variable, and sending all the results to the page. This means that you can just access the specific id in the view by accessing the objects properties without re initiating the `$id` variable.

`<form action="{{ url('driver_payment_history/'.$payment_details->driver_id) }}" method="post">`

If you do use this, you can remove `$new_var_id`(or whatever you named it) from your controller, as well as removing it from `compact()`